# Regex - Match first occurrence within string, do not return anything before it

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm doing a search and replace in Notepad++ and am looking for a regex that will literally give me the first `(` in a given string, so I can replace it.

I am not interested in any preceding or succeeding characters, literally just the first `(`.

An example string is:

```
"starLan(11), -- Deprecated via RFC3635 ethernetCsmacd (6) should be used instead
```

I'd like to find the first `(` (near `starLan(11)` in this case) so I can replace that character with something else.

It should not match any other `(` in the same line, so in this case it should not match the second `(` near `(6)`.

All of the examples I've come across seem to be returning everything up to and including the given character, which is not what I'm after in this case.

Comment: So, why is *returning everything up to and including the given character* a problem? Have you heard of capture groups and backreferences?

Comment: I have not, maybe that might be a simpler way, can you explain further?

Comment: It is so simple you can see the 2 answers and more to come I guess.

Comment: I'm not denying how simple it is, but if I don't know I ask, I thought that was the whole premise of SO, so that what some know and others don't can be shared. To down vote my question due to either it's simplicity or some implied notion that I should know this is just absurd though. And, as per my question, I did search this before asking, so it's not like I didn't do my homework or something. I obviously just didn't know what to search for, since I didn't know about the concept of back references and therefore couldn't search for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would match the following pattern :

```
^([^(]*)\((.*)$
```

And replace it with this :

```
\1X\2
```

Where `X` is the text you want to replace your `(` with.

It uses back-references to refer to the parts before and after the first `(`.

---

Edit : as mentioned by OP, matching `^([^(]*)\(` and replacing with `\1X` is enough.

Comment: Can be simplified to `^([^(]*)\(` and the replace part to `\1X`, but works great. Thank you!

Comment: Indeed, I was afraid a replace all might replace multiple occurrences in a line, but the leading `^`  forbids that.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this

```
^(.*?)\(
```

the text captured inside () will be available in back reference $1. so you can replace it like:

```
$1someText
```

where someText is the text you want to put in place of removed '('

if you want the text after removed '(' to remain intact as well, you can use:

```
^(.*?)\((.*)
```

and replacement as:

```
$1someText$2
```

Comment: This matches the last `(` in the string.

Comment: @cogumel0 [please check this](https://regex101.com/r/tC8nB7/3) and i just checked it in notepad++ too. could you post any link to show it's not working?

Comment: i updated the previous link to show match with my answer for the text after removed '('. that seems to be working too. both in regex101 and notepad++. if you can verify that it's working, would you please kindly remove the downvote.

Comment: What you posted was `^(.*)?\((.*)`. What you put on the link provided is `^(.*?)\((.*)`. Two different regexes

Comment: hmm..my mistake then.